# jaxb xs:element ignore empty list

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling

i have a schema file like

```
 <xs:complexType name="Autorisation">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="roles" type="Roles"/>
    </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Roles">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="role" type="Role" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Role">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="type" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:element name="dateDebut" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    <xs:element name="dateFin" type="xs:dateTime"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

it generate something like that :

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name = "role")
protected List<Role> roles;
```

When i create an xml file with `JAXB.marshal(input, Output);` with an empty roles list, the xml file generated contains `<role/>`

How can i avoid that ?

Thanks !! :)

Comment: As written your schema doesn't allow an empty list at all (without an explicit `minOccurs="0"` on `role` it gets the default minimum of 1).

Comment: i've tried it and got same result :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name = "role")
protected List<Role> roles;
```

Then one of the following will happen:

1. If `roles` contains items you will get:

   ```
   <roles>
       <role>...</role>
       <role>...</role>
   </roles>
   ```
2. If `roles` is an empty list you will get:

   ```
   <roles/>
   ```
3. If `roles` is null then the `roles` element will not appear.

---

**For More Information**

I have written more about this on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html

---

### UPDATE

> I also use "dozer" to convert Object into another object, so empty
>   list are never null. Is there no way to tell JAXB ignore empty list ?

You could add some marshal event call back methods on your domain class to adjust the `List` property before and after marshalling (see:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback).

```
void beforeMarshal(Marshaller) {
  if(roles != null && roles.isEmpty()) {
      roles = null;
  }
}

void afterMmarshal(Marshaller) {
    if(null == roles) {
        roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I also use "dozer" to convert Object into another object, so empty list are never null.
Is there no way to tell JAXB ignore empty list ? :/